# Неизвестный отступ на Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, мобильные-приложения

При использовании шаблона с меню в Android Studio столкнулся с неприятным отступом сверху, который смещает все остальные элементы вниз. Можно ли как-то исправить это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:queryHint="Введите название, ISBN или автора книги" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: вообще желательно разметку прикрепить, а то как-то можно только руками помахать чтобы отступ убрался

Comment: @Andrew так дело в том, что это даже не отступ, а какой-то ToolBar.

Comment: без разметки сложно помочь!

Comment: @Andrew добавил разметку

Comment: А это точно вся разметка? У вас не фрагмент во фрагменте или что то такое? В приведенной разметке проблем не видно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это лишь один фрагмент из всего шаблона Bottom Navigation Activity. Проблема в том, что сверху есть неприятный Bar, который загораживает контент, либо сдвигает его вниз, под меню.

Comment: Если сверху что-то есть - уберите это. Через стили, например, как вам в ответе писали или из разметки, если оно там.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это не работает, я пробовал.

Comment: Тогда вот вам ещё идея - в ScrollView должен быть только один ребёнок и тот, обычно, контейнер. ПОпробуйте обернуть ваш SearchView в LinearLayout например. Может, это поможет. Если нет - покажите больше кода. Например всю иерархию отображаемых файлов разметки. Если у вас это стандартный гугловый пример-шаблон, то ожидаемо, что он слабо модифицируем. Ими почти никто никогда не пользуется, засим там могут быть незамеченные разработчиками особенности.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб с LinearLayout не работает, и это было ожидаемо. Тогда буду переделывать.

Comment: Я не понял, что вы хотели сказать последним своим комментарием(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб исправил эту ошибку, в MainActivity был padding для ActionBar.

Answer (score -2):

Уже исправил данную "ошибку". В MainActivity был padding под ActionBar, но шаблоны от Google всё равно лучше не использовать.